# How to chart points on a stretched line

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm somewhat math literate but need help on a formula.  Lets say I have a straight line that starts at 8500 and ends at 11,700 with seven points in between at irregular intervals between each other.  I want to stretch the old line so that the new start point is still 8500 but the end point is now 23,400.  I want to determine the new points for the seven spaces in between.  It seems like there should be a formula to do this.

I don't know that it matters, but the points in between I am interested in are 8850, 9550, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10450 and 10950.  But it doesn't seem like those should matter as I ought to be able to have a formula that I plug in any number between 8500 and 11700 for the old line and come up with the new point.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

TR

Answer (score 1):

Take the distance from one point to $8500$, multiply it by the amount the whole line is being stretched by ($\frac{23400-8500}{11700-8500}=\frac{149}{32}$), and add that distance to $8500$ to get the new number. For example, your first point $8850$ is a distance of $350$ from $8500$. That distance gets stretched by a factor of $\frac{149}{32}$ so that the new distance from $8500$ is $\approx 1629.69$ and thus the new number is $10129.69$. In general, the function would be $f:a\mapsto k(a-z)+z$ where $z$ is the number that is not being moved (the "zero" as linear algebraists would call it), and $k$ is the factor that the line is being stretched by.

Comment: Thank you very, very much.  I knew it had to be "simple" - this makes me miss math.  I always thought learning/figuring this stuff out was fun but at university I went a completely different direction.  Again, thank you both.

Answer (score 0):

There is a formula.  $f(x) = (x-8,500)*14,900/3,200 + 8,500  = 4.65625x -31078.125 $

Or, if you don't have a calculator $f(x) = (x - 8,500)*149/32 + 8,500$ will be easiest.  Subtract 8,500 (to get the two lines aligned at zero); divide by 32 and multiply by 149 (to do the stretch); add 8,500 (to relign at the 8,500 "starting point").

Comment: Thank you very, very much.  I knew it had to be "simple" - this makes me miss math.  I always thought learning/figuring this stuff out was fun but at university I went a completely different direction.  Again, thank you both.

Answer (score 0):

For this type of problem I typically fall back to two utility functions:

$Lerp(t, a, b) = (1-t)a + tb$

$Unlerp(v, a, b) = (v-a)/(b-a)$

In the first, $t$ takes a value between $0$ and $1$ and the function maps $t$ to a value between $a$ and $b$. In the second, $v$ takes a value between $a$ and $b$ and the function maps $v$ to a value between $0$ and $1$.

Using these, you can map from your first range to your second range using:

$Remap(v) = Lerp(Unlerp(v, 8500, 11700), 8500, 23400)$